# ggplot add horizontal line to grouped categorical data and share legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is some code that makes a categorical bar chart and places a mean line on the chart. The problem is that the legends are separate and I can't figure out how to stick them together. I think I have made a dummy variable in the past and included it in the scale_manual arguments but geom_vline doesn't handle the "fill" mappings. Any ideas?

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)

y = mean(mtcars$mpg)
x = unique(mtcars$cyl)
meanDf <- 
  data.frame(x, y )


mtcars$mean = y
mtcars$group = "mean"

mtcars %>%


ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg, fill = factor(carb))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_hline(data = meanDf, aes(yintercept = y, color = "")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("blue", "red", "green", "white", "black", "yellow"), labels = paste("myLabel", 1:6)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = "red", label = "myLabel") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(color = "black", fill = "white"))
```

Comment: I am not sure that you should be combining legends in this case. The fill colour is by group, but the mean is across all groups, so they are separate summaries. Having a "line per filled group" would imply that the mean is for that group.

Comment: Thanks but this is just a quick graph to demonstrate the issue I am trying to resolve. These data are fake but my need is the same as stated in the question

Comment: Can you clarify what the output should look like. Do you want (1) the legend to look like the output of your current code, but as one legend? Or (2) do you want to combine the fill and the vline, so each of the filled boxes 1-6 has a line through the centre?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use only the `fill` scale and make use of custom key glyph.

1. Set the color for the `geom_hline` as an argument instead of mapping on the `color` aes. Instead map a constant e.g. `""` on the `fill` aes. A Drawback is that we get a warning.
2. Add an additional color and label to `scale_fill_manual`.
3. To get a line as the key glyph for the `geom_hline` I make use of a custom key glyph which conditionally on the `fill` color switches between `draw_key_path` and the default key glyph for `geom_col`. To make this work I use a `"red2"` as the additional fill color for the hline which I switch to `"red"` inside the custom key glyph function.

```r
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)

y = mean(mtcars$mpg)
x = unique(mtcars$cyl)
meanDf <- data.frame(x, y )

mtcars$mean = y
mtcars$group = "mean"

draw_key_cust <- function(data, params, size) {
  if (data$fill %in% c("red2")){
    data$colour <- "red"
    data$fill <- NA
    draw_key_path(data, params, size)  
  } else
    GeomCol$draw_key(data, params, size)
}

mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg, fill = factor(carb))) +
  geom_hline(data = meanDf, aes(yintercept = y, fill = ""), color = "red") +
  geom_col(key_glyph = "cust") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = NULL, values = c("red2", "blue", "red", "green", "white", "black", "yellow"), labels = c("label", paste("myLabel", 1:6))) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(color = "black", fill = "white"))
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think for readability, it's better to separate them out. However, for formatting purpose, you sure can bring them as close as you want by dropping the `legend.title` (not just assigning it an empty string) and adjusting the `legend.margin` and `legned.spacing`. For instance,

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)

y = mean(mtcars$mpg)
x = unique(mtcars$cyl)
meanDf <- 
  data.frame(x, y )


mtcars$mean = y
mtcars$group = "mean"

mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg, fill = factor(carb))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_hline(data = meanDf, aes(yintercept = y, color = "")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("blue", "red", "green", "white", "black", "yellow"), labels = paste("myLabel", 1:6)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = "red", label = "myLabel") + 
  theme(
    legend.title = element_blank(), 
    legend.margin = margin(t = 0, b = 0, r = 2, l = 2),
    legend.spacing.y = unit(.5, "pt")
  )
```

Output
[image: res]

Comment: Thanks! However, I am using custom formatting to the themes that draws a box around the legends so for that example this won't really work. I updated my code to reflect this.  I really need to have them be part of the same legend. The need for the custom formatting is not something I can change