# Neatly place 2 legends together in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to get my ggplot2 legends to sit together well.

I have a fill legend and a colour legend and I want them to be over multiple rows at the base of the plot but with the colour legend continuing directly after the fill legend, rather than starting a new column.

I've made a quick example and desired output (just made in paint) below to illustrate

```r
  library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
testdf <- data.frame(mon = factor(month.abb, levels = month.abb), y = rnorm(84,mean = 20, sd = 10), cat = rep(paste0("class ",letters[1:7]), each =  12))

thresholds <- data.frame(ThresholdNm = c("low","high"), ThresholdVal = c(110,150))

ggplot(testdf, aes(x = mon, y = y, fill = cat))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  geom_hline(data = thresholds, aes(yintercept = ThresholdVal, colour = ThresholdNm))+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","black"))+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title = element_blank())+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow=3,byrow=FALSE,order = 1),colour = guide_legend(nrow=2,byrow=FALSE,order = 2))
```

This is what I get:

[image]

But what I am hoping for is this:

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Maybe checkout the accepted response to this question where I suggested how legends could be merged. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71073879/how-to-add-legend-to-plot-from-causalimpact-package/71094435#71094435

Comment: I bet this particular customization is easier to do manually afterwards. Eg if you exported into powerpoint with `officer` and `rvg` you could move and align the legend pieces exactly where you want them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting my answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70748695/12993861) to your case you could achieve your desired result using a custom key glyph like so:

1. Basically this involves mapping `ThresholdVal` on the `fill` aes in `geom_hline`. Doing so will add the items to the fill legend too.
2. Create a color palette which could be used for both the `fill` and the `color` scale and which takes care of the right order of the items.
3. Write custom key glyph function which conditional on the color value switches between the key glyph used for bars and the one used for `geom_hline`
4. Remove the color legend.
5. Use theme options to get a border around all legend keys including the ones for the hlines.

```r
library(ggplot2)

nclass <- nlevels(factor(testdf$cat))
pal <- c(scales::hue_pal()(nclass), "red", "black")
names(pal) <- c(levels(factor(testdf$cat)), "high", "low")

draw_key_cust <- function(data, params, size) {
  if (data$fill %in% c("red", "black")) {
    data$colour <- data$fill
    data$fill <- NA
    draw_key_path(data, params, size)
  } else {
    GeomCol$draw_key(data, params, size)
  }
}

ggplot(testdf, aes(x = mon, y = y, fill = cat)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", key_glyph = "cust") +
  geom_hline(data = thresholds, aes(yintercept = ThresholdVal, colour = ThresholdNm, fill = ThresholdNm)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal, aesthetics = c("fill", "color")) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title = element_blank(), 
        legend.key = element_rect(linewidth = .25 * .pt, color = "white")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 3, byrow = FALSE, order = 1), colour = "none")
#> Warning in geom_hline(data = thresholds, aes(yintercept = ThresholdVal, :
#> Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill
```

[image]

Comment: Sweet, thanks! I never knew about `key_glyph`s, think this could have solved some awful solutions I've created in the past using `override.aes`